# Creating a Javascript bundle with a few components for reuse

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I have a backend rendered page (django in case it matters) which I want to soup up a little using some components from PrimeVue and a markdown editor packaged as a vue component. Right now, we have a few small animations using jquery for which we include jquery from a CDN directly into our pages. A few months ago, we needed to spice up a page using some more client side interactivity and we included vue.js via a CDN onto that page (dropping jquery) and then wrote some javascript in an index.js that we also loaded up from a CDN and got our work done. This is the current state of affairs. The page currently looks like this

```
<html>
  ....
 <script src="https://cdn/vue.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/index.js"></script>
```

The div `#mainvue` is where vue runs and does what it needs to.

This is where we are now.

Using plain vue is okay. Now, I'd like to throw in a few components from primevue as well as a 3rd party markdown editor that's wrapped as vue component. I want to bundle all of these as wel as plain vue itself into a single javascript bundle that I can throw onto a CDN and include into all my pages. Then my devs can do their day to day work in the `index.js`.

Is this a reasonable approach and if so, how do I do it? I'm not familiar with the javascript ecosystem. If not, what's the right way to solve this problem. I don't want to go all the way SPA and REST API. I just want to use a few 3rd party components and vue on a simple otherwise backend rendered page.

Comment: Are you using Webpack or just plain JS?

Comment: I'm not "using" webpack since I don't know how to. I have tried it along with several of the other tools that I've tagged the question with but none of them got me anywhere. My thought is that if I `npm install` all the components I need and then run `webpack`, I should get a bundle but apparently, it's not that straightforward.

Comment: Have you tried using vue cli yet? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library which actually webpack but it less config.

Comment: I did but I'm not really sure how to *use* it. Like I said, I'm not familiar with the ecosystem so I'm not sure how to go about this. I wasn't able to find a tutorial that does exactly what I've asked the question and that's really what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention you don't want to "go all the way SPA," a reasonable hybrid to is to use Vue in MPA (multi-page app) mode. This will require using a vue-cli/webpack configuration to compile your Vue components into bundles, but once you have this build pipeline, these bundles can used in individual Django templates via [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader). Information can be passed from Django via template variables directly as Vue component properties.

Re bundling, yes you can bundle all these resources into a single JS using this method, but it's nearly as easy (and far more performant) to create one or more common bundles that represent shared logic (third party libs, invidual components, even Vue itself) and then pick and choose from among these bundles as needed on individual Django templates.

The steps to implement are a bit too involved to post directly here, but I've written a series of articles [Django + Vue -- Best of Both Frontends](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-django-best-of-both-frontends-701307871478) that explains.  There's also a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/ilikerobots/cookiecutter-vue-django) for boostrapping new projects using this method.  I realize you already have a site, but you can perhaps adapt the implementation there.

Good hacking!

Comment: This sounds good. I will look at your articles. Thanks!